# Insert id attribute to styled components created by react-emotion

Tags: reactjs, emotion

The basic use of *styling* plain HTML elements with `react-emotion` as React components is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'react-emotion';

const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;
```

The given code would give us something like this:

```
<div class="css-gf43fxd ferwf23sd"></div>
```

Is there anyway I can add an `id` attibute to that generated HTML element? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add the `id` attribute when you are using this component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'react-emotion';

const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;

// and when you want to use this component add id attribute

<StyledContainer id="some-id">...</StyledContainer>
```

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of this. It's so simple and basic. LOL. Anyway, thanks for this!